# Visual Studio 2013 Team Explorer window displaying inaccurate TFS status / capabilities, difficulty changing collections

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs

After upgrading from Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4 to Update 5, I am experiencing some odd behavior between Visual Studio and TFS (also 2013.5).

**Issues/Symptoms**
 * Team Explorer claims its disconnected from TFS, even though Source Control Explorer works as expected.
 * The number of buttons in Team Explorer for projects has been reduced down to 3.
 * Changing projects between TFS collections (on the same TFS app tier server) isn't working correctly. The change doesn't happen. Instead, I have to go out and open the solution in the other collection from disk. Then the active collection is "noted" by Visual Studio.

**What I've tried**

- Running devenv.exe /ResetSettings and multiple other switches
- Repairing the installation using both the 2013.5.exe download and the ISO download from MSDN

None of the above has changed the Team Explorer behavior issues.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the Team Explorer 2013: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description `Team Explorer for projects has been reduced down to 3` seems related to source control bindings or workspace mappings. You could double check this to narrow down the issue.

As a simple way you could try :

1. Delete your old workspace. Need to check in local pending changes
   first and back up your local files.
2. Create a new clean workspace and mapping it to server.  Then get
   down the latest version from server to local.
3. Clear TFS and VS cache. Reload VS to open the project or solution

Also take a look at the **Event View** to see if there are some related info of the issue.